# css formatting does not return to previous formatting after an <a href...>text</a> tag pair

Tags: html, css

I have a page which is not formatting properly, or at least not formatting as I expect it to.

Below is a simplified version of the code.

```
<div ...>
  <div class="db_notes">
    <pre>
Some Text. 
<span class="blue">Lots more text that may be one line or multiple lines and is
retrieved from a database in preformatted form and often has one or more 
<a href="...">links</a> within the preformatted text.</span>
Some Additional text.
<span class="blue">More text that may be one or more lines and is reformatted 
and comes from a database and often contains one or more <a href="...">links</a> 
within the text.</span>
And more text.
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only the font color is changed by the `<span class="blue">`.

The color of the text between the `<span class="blue">` and the `<a href...>` is blue (as desired), but the color of the text between the `</a>` and the `</span>` is black (instead of blue).

Any idea as to why, after the `</a>` tag, the text color does not return to blue?

Thanks!

John

*** UPDATE ***

First, thanks to all who created examples to test the premise that the color SHOULD be blue after the </a> tag!  You proved I'm not crazy! (or not completely crazy).

I made a copy of the example at JS Bin and on the copy page pasted in a major section of the page with the text color problem.  To my amazement, the text after the </a> tag is blue, as it should be.

Next I looked through the CSS to find any style elements that might affect the div, span, a, or pre tags, and put them in the CSS section on JS Bin.  The resulting formatting still looks correct, with the text after the </a> tag still blue.

So then I copied the entire CSS file and pasted it into the CSS section on JS Bin.  That broke it.  The text after the </a> tag changed to black, which was the problem I've been having with the page.

So, somewhere in this massive CSS file there is something which is affecting how this page renders.  Why, I don't know.  I've always been under the impression that after an in-line closing tag the formatting should return to that in effect before the opening tag, but somehow something is changing that behavior.

It is now about 2:15 AM here, so I'm going to call it a day, get some sleep, and take a fresh look at it after some rest.

John

*** UPDATE ***

I've gone through the entire page making sure that all tags are matched, the nesting correct (no DIV elements inside a SPAN, etc.), and it still does not format properly.

I can't spend any more time on it, so I've come up with a kludge - close the span immediately before the <a href...> and open a new <span class="blue"> immediately after the </a>, as shown below.  I know it shouldn't be necessary, but if that is what it takes to make it work, so be it.  So, here is the revised simplified code.

```
<div ...>
  <div class="db_notes">
    <pre>
Some Text. 
<span class="blue">Lots more text that may be one line or multiple lines and is
retrieved from a database in preformatted form and often has one or more 
</span><a href="...">links</a><span class="blue"> within the preformatted text.</span>
Some Additional text.
<span class="blue">More text that may be one or more lines and is reformatted 
and comes from a database and often contains one or more 
</span><a href="...">links</a><span class="blue"> 
within the text.</span>
And more text.
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

I still would like to know why the browsers are behaving in this manner.  If anyone has any thoughts as to what is happening to cause the formatting to break down after the </a> tag, I'd love to hear them.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Can you go to www.jsfiddle.net and build a working example and provide a link to the fiddle on your question?

Comment: I am getting the correct output with this css:
`.blue {color:blue;}`
And your html.

Comment: welcome to SO, if I assume you are using `color:blue` for `span` then the text inside `span` will be only blue color. rest font will be `black` color. have a look at Jsbin link. http://jsbin.com/jiracepileha/1/edit

Comment: Hmmm.  I haven't used jsfiddle before, so some experimentation will be necessary.  This may take a while.

Comment: Hi Error & Kheema Pandey.  Yes, that is the CSS I'm using, and the output of the example at jsbin is what I was expecting, but not what I'm getting.  When I view the page source the tags match up, but the text goes to black after the &lt;/a&gt; tag.  I'm going to try to upload a more detailed example.

Comment: You should include an example that actually reproduces the issue *in the question itself*, and do that by editing the question to contain that.

Comment: `somewhere in this massive CSS file there is something which is affecting` That's what inspect element is for. It will show you what styles are applying where. If you want an extra pair of eyes, post a link to the jsbin example you were referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get into a source code file for another project (locked for editing), so while waiting I took another look at the problem page.

In looking through the page in Firebug I noticed that while the page source has exactly one <a name="top"> tag, the Firebug display shows multiple instances of that tag.  Strange.

Then I looked closer and noticed that there was no </a> tag matching the <a name="top"> tag.

After replacing:

```
<a name="top">
```

with:

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

The page works correctly!!!

At some point the web site needs to be updated to replace the:

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

...and other "a name=" tags with:

```
<a id="top"></a>
```

...tags to comply with HTML 5, but with over 2,300 dynamic pages, most with from one to thirty <a name="text"> tags, it will be a long time before there will be funding for such an effort.  Another reason why some tags and options need to be supported for backward compatibility.

Thanks again to all who have contributed assistance in any form!

Best wishes,

John

Answer (score -1):

The color of the text between the `<span class="blue">` and the `<a href...>` is blue (as desired), but the color of the text between them `</a>` and the `</span>` is black (instead of blue).

If I assume you are using `.blue {color: blue;}` this property for `span` then it will change the text color blue for text which is inside the `span` tag. The text out of `<span>` will be black.

Have a look at this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jiracepileha/1/edit)**.
in this case, I've changed the `<span>` color from `blue` to `red` and you see `<a>` tag text is still blue which is by default.

**Note:** only the text inside `span` will be in `blue` color that not include the text inside the`<a>` tag. by default giving a link to `<a>` tag its change to blue color.

Comment: This does not answer the question “why, after the `</a>` tag, the text color does not return to blue” (which cannot be answered without additional information, specifically code that actually produces the problem).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela so it is my fault that I gave the answer here. who you guys are demoralize people by giving downvoting if someone try to give an answer. This is the reason now a days people are like to downvoting and voting to close the question. OP wants desire result as I shared with him.